# Object is more then 1 child, now what?

Tags: java

I have an abstract class called Person.

A person has multiple child classes e.g. Driver, Sorter, Manager.
Each of which has its unique methods, and the ones shared e.g. name/age/location, etc and so I then thought that an abstract parent-class would be the solution. (Person)

Yet now I face a new problem, What if a person is both?
Now I have an 'Object' which is a Driver but also a Sorter.
So when he/she calls in sick, Person has a method called reportSick()
But when object driver.reportSick() is being called, there is a chance that there is another object for the same Person that is a Sorter.

It looks strange to me to have 2 objects for the same thing (The person in this case)

What am I overlooking/doing wrong/misunderstanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go this way:

- Make the interface(or abstract class if needed) `Profession` and implement your classes (`Driver, Sorter, Manager`) from it.
- Make `Person` not abstract and add there field `List<Profession>`. And when you need some methods call it in cycle for each `Profession`.

Comment: Yeah, this is much simpler and more concise than my solution. Abstracting out into a separate `Profession` and having `Person` be a final class sounds very clean to me.

Answer (score 0):

You've discovered one of the fundamental limitations of inheritance: It creates a very tight coupling between parent and child. "A Sorter is a Person". Not "A Sorter is some other kind of Person", but literally "A Sorter is directly an extension of Person and nothing else".

You can use composition to make explicit who to call next in the "inheritance" chain.

```
public interface Person {
  public void reportSick();
}

public class OrdinaryPerson implements Person {
  public void reportSick() {
    // An "ordinary" person does nothing when they report sick.
  }
}

public class Driver implements Person {
  private Person next;

  public Driver(Person next) {
    this.next = next;
  }

  public void reportSick() {
    // Driver specific stuff goes here ...
    this.next.reportSick();
  }

}

// Then do the same for Sorter and Manager ...
```

Now, if a person is "just" a driver, you can represent them as

```
new Driver(new OrdinaryPerson())
```

This person is both a driver and an ordinary person (`OrdinaryPerson` is our null object; it has no actual behaviors to speak of, so we can use it to break our chain).

If a person is both a driver and a sorter, we can write

```
new Driver(new Sorter(new OrdinaryPerson()))
```

and assuming `Driver` and `Sorter` each call the inner `reportSick` method, they'll both get called when you call the method on this aggregate we've constructed.

Comment: Thanks for you clearence, What if my Driver later decides to become a Sorter as well or vice versa? And they both have a innerclass called Scheme yet they both take different parameters, How do I draw both scheme from the OrdinaryPerson?

Comment: If the identities of these characters can change at any time, then it definitely shouldn't be the object's class. An object's class never changes in the course of a Java program. Any part of a thing that can change should be a field on that object. Take a look at @Константин's answer. I recommend going with that approach

Answer (score 0):

Driver, Manager & Sorter are just special kind of service that any person is efficient with. It may be one or more.
So, best way to declare interfaces for them and declare method for each without body.
Now declare class which extends abstract class & implements one or more interfaces.

```
public abstract class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String location;

    // Constructor (Must)
    public Person(String name, int age, String location) {
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
        this.location=location;
    }
}

public interface Driver {
    void isDriving(String name, int age, String location);
}

public interface Sorter {
    void isSorting(String name, int age, String location);
}

public interface Manager {
    void isManaging(String name, int age, String location);
}

public class Person1 extends Person implements Driver, Manager {
/*
    Properties, Constructors & Getters/Setters
*/
    @overrides
    public void isDriving(String name, int age, String location) {
    //  Driving Function Body
    }

    @overrides
    public void isManaging(String name, int age, String location) {
    //  Managing Function Body
    }    
}
```

Comment: The class 'Person1' looks to be a refference to an object? So peter is Person1? or can Peter and Harry both be Person1? And if so, will that mean if i extend the proffessions with lets say another 5, That i need to create a 'inbetween' class like Person1 for every possible Profession combination? Person1 implements Driver, Manager Person2 implements Manager, Sorter Person3 implements Driver, Manager, Sorter ?

Comment: But every profession provides special kind of service. That's why you have to say 'What To Do'. If Peter is a driver & manager, then peter should implement both and defines 'How To Do'. Otherwise, how will you introduce a new profession ?

Comment: Either you will use Association and have to use Heterogeneous property variable for this. I am not saying that this process is ultimate. If anyone provide a better solution, please tag me. I am ready to learn.